# Stop regex from spanning across unrequired content

Tags: c#, regex

I need to extract a series of meaningful values from a file. The basic pattern for the values I need to match looks like:

```
"indicator\..+?"\[true\]
```

Unfortunately, in places this is spanning across quite a bit of content to get a true match, and the lazy quantifier (?) is not being as lazy as I'd like.

How do I modify the above so that out of the following:

> "indicator.value here"[false],"other content","more other
>   content","indicator don't match this one because the full stop is missing"[true],"indicator.this is the
>   value I want matched"[true]

only this value is returned: "indicator.this is the value I want matched"[true]

Currently, that whole string is being returned by my above regex.

Comment: Thanks John Saunders, will avoid this in future.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming commas are the delimiter - simply avoid matching on them:

```
@"""indicator\.[^,]+?""\[true\]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `"indicator\.(.*)?"\[true\]` instead and see if that helps.  I think the lazy only applies to the `*` operator.  I vaguely remember having this issue years ago.

Comment: Even if true, you are missing a `.`

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the discard technique by discarding the pattern you don't want. So, you could have something like this:

```
"indicator\..+?"\[false\]|"indicator\.(.+?)"\[true\]
Discard this pattern --^ Capture this --^
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/pY5eE0/1)**

Match information

```
MATCH 1
1.  [150-182]   `this is the value I want matched`
```